# Copy a whole directory structure in Chef

Tags: ruby, directory, chef

I have a directory structure (sample data) that I want to copy from within a Chef recipe. It seems the only way to do this is to explicitly create each individual directory and file:

```
directory "/mnt/data/experiment1/dataset1" do
   recursive true
   only_if { node.chef_environment == "dev" }
end


directory "/mnt/data/experiment1/dataset2" do
   recursive true
   only_if { node.chef_environment == "dev" }
end

directory "/mnt/data/experiment2/dataset1" do
   recursive true
   only_if { node.chef_environment == "dev" }
end


directory "/mnt/data/experiment1/dataset2" do
   recursive true
   only_if { node.chef_environment == "dev" }
end


cookbook_file "/mnt/data/experiment1/dataset1/testfile1.txt" do
   owner "atom"
   group "atom"
   mode "0644"
   source "sampledata/experiment1/dataset1/testfile1.txt"
   only_if { node.chef_environment == "dev"}
end

...
```

Is there a way to simply recursively copy an entire directory structure from the cookbook? Specifying the name of each file inside the recipe seems redundant and error-prone (ie, if we add a file to the tree but forget to reference it in the recipe, it won't be copied.)

I guess a hack workaround would be to work out where all the chef files get copied to on the target machine and do a `cp -r` but is there something cleaner?

Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not using `remote_directory` resource.
It's intended exactly for that.

See: https://docs.chef.io/resource_remote_directory.html

Comment: That looks right - is it new by any chance? Also it seems that `remote_file` and `remote_directory` behave completely differently (let alone `cookbook_file` and `file`). What a confusing mess...

Comment: It is confusing. There are a lot of discussions about that.
Anyway - you should check Puppet. That's synonym for "messy" :)

Answer (score 1):

[file_cache_path](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Chef+Configuration+Settings#ChefConfigurationSettings-filecachepath) will tell you where the cookbooks are located on the target machine

Therefore you just need to sync your cookbook's directory within file_cache_path to your target location. You could do that with a `cp -r`, a ruby_block using [FileUtils#cp_r](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-cp_r), or some other cleverness I haven't thought of.

Comment: Hmm. Well, it turns out that directories under files/default aren't copied to the target machine anyway. Maybe the simplest way would be to provide all the files in a zip, copy that, then unzip it.